# How do I make Tensorflow use more of my RAM?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to build a GAN with tensorflow/keras. I have 32GB of RAM and I even added another 70GB of virtual memory on top of that. When I try to use about 40000 images of (128, 128, 3), tensorflow stops and I get:

```
2021-01-22 00:12:42.680822: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:80] Allocation of 9232121856 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
```

However, the max amount of RAM it used was 25GB out of my theoretical 100GB. Even if tensorflow couldn't use virtual memory, its only using 80% of my memory sticks. Changing the batch size and # of trainable parameters did nothing. Is it talking about the VRAM? Am I doing something wrong? How can I make tensorflow use more of my RAM?
I am currently using:
python 3.8
tf-gpu 2.4.0rc1
keras 2.4.3\

Edit: I tried lowering the resolution of the images to (64, 64, 3) which let me use my whole dataset of 106000. It trained this time but still gave the 10% memory warning, but it only used 70% of my memory sticks.

Full Code:

```
import imageio, os, PIL, random, pickle
from glob import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import time
from cv2 import cv2
from IPython import display

config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(
        per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.725))
for device in tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices("GPU"):
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device, True)
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(session)

IMG_SIZE = 128
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 500000
noise_dim = 100
num_examples_to_generate = 96

paths = glob('F:/DATA/E621_GAN/**', recursive=True)
del paths[0]

print(int((len(paths)) / BATCH_SIZE), "STEPS")


def make_generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(int(IMG_SIZE/8)*int(IMG_SIZE/8)*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(noise_dim,)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Reshape((int(IMG_SIZE/8), int(IMG_SIZE/8), 256)))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, int(IMG_SIZE/8), int(IMG_SIZE/8), 256) # Note: None is the batch size

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, (7, 7), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, int(IMG_SIZE/8), int(IMG_SIZE/8), 256)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, int(IMG_SIZE/4), int(IMG_SIZE/4), 128)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, int(IMG_SIZE/2), int(IMG_SIZE/2), 64)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

    model.summary()
    return model

generator = make_generator_model()

noise = tf.random.normal([1, noise_dim])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)

def make_discriminator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))

    model.summary()
    return model

discriminator = make_discriminator_model()
decision = discriminator(generated_image)

# This method returns a helper function to compute cross entropy loss
cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    real_loss = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_output), real_output)
    fake_loss = cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_output), fake_output)
    total_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
    return total_loss


def generator_loss(fake_output):
    return cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(fake_output), fake_output)

generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)

checkpoint_dir = 'D:/DATA/E621_SAVES/checkpoints/'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_optimizer=generator_optimizer,
                                 discriminator_optimizer=discriminator_optimizer,
                                 generator=generator,
                                 discriminator=discriminator)

checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))

seed = tf.random.normal([num_examples_to_generate, noise_dim])

@tf.function
def train_step(images):
    noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, noise_dim])

    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
        generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)

        real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)
        fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

        gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
        disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
    return gen_loss, disc_loss

print("Loading Dataset")
images = []
# 1 GB of images = about 50 GB of data
for i in range(len(paths)-60000):
    try:
        image_path = paths[i]
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = np.float32(image)
        images.append((image - 127.5) / 127.5)
    except:
        pass
print("Finished Loading Dataset")

images = np.array(images)
print(images.shape)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images).shuffle(99999999).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
print("Finished Organizing Dataset")

epoch_save = 0
try:
    data = [epoch_save, seed]
    with open('D:/DATA/E621_SAVES/checkpoints/epoch.pkl', 'rb') as save:
        data = pickle.load(save)
        epoch_save = data[0]
        seed = data[1]
except:
    print("No pickle found")

def train(dataset, epochs, epoch_save, seed):
    for epoch in range(epochs - epoch_save):
        start = time.time()
        epoch_save += 1

        gen_loss_list, disc_loss_list = [], []
        for image_batch in dataset:
            t = train_step(image_batch)
            gen_loss_list.append(t[0])
            disc_loss_list.append(t[1])
        

        g_loss = sum(gen_loss_list) / len(gen_loss_list)
        d_loss = sum(disc_loss_list) / len(disc_loss_list)

        display.clear_output(wait=True)
        generate_and_save_images(generator,
                             epoch_save,
                             seed)

        if (epoch + 1) % 25 == 0:
            checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)
            data = [epoch_save, seed]
            with open('D:/DATA/E621_SAVES/checkpoints/epoch.pkl', 'wb') as save:
                pickle.dump(data, save)


    
        print(f'Epoch {epoch_save}: gen_loss={g_loss}, disc_loss={d_loss}, time: {np.round(time.time()-start, 4)} sec')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15.36,10.24))
def generate_and_save_images(model, epoch, test_input):
    predictions = model(test_input, training=False)

    ax = []
    for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
        ax.append(plt.subplot(8,12,i+1))
        plt.imshow(predictions[i, :, :, 0] * 127.5 + 127.5)

    for a in ax:
        a.set_xticks([])
        a.set_yticks([])

    fig.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, wspace=0, hspace=0)

    plt.savefig('D:/DATA/E621_SAVES/epoch_{:04d}.png'.format(epoch), dpi=100)
    plt.clf()

train(train_dataset, EPOCHS, epoch_save, seed)
```

Output:

```
2021-01-22 00:12:03.372768: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.743931: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-22 00:12:05.744894: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.765514: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3070 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.725GHz coreCount: 46 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-22 00:12:05.765726: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.775582: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.775689: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.778527: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.779685: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.785534: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.787678: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.788518: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.788665: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-22 00:12:05.789173: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-01-22 00:12:05.790050: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3070 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.725GHz coreCount: 46 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-22 00:12:05.790231: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.790305: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.790383: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.790582: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.790704: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.790816: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.790887: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.790954: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:05.791139: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-22 00:12:06.170269: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-01-22 00:12:06.170365: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-01-22 00:12:06.170489: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-01-22 00:12:06.170738: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5939 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-01-22 00:12:06.171371: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
WARNING:tensorflow:From f:\PYTHON\GAN\GAN.py:16: The name tf.keras.backend.set_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session instead.

1671 STEPS
2021-01-22 00:12:08.495267: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3070 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.725GHz coreCount: 46 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-22 00:12:08.495435: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:08.495586: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:08.495694: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:08.495766: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:08.495835: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:08.495905: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:08.495982: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:08.496054: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:08.496143: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-22 00:12:08.496223: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-01-22 00:12:08.496293: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-01-22 00:12:08.496340: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-01-22 00:12:08.496454: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5939 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-01-22 00:12:08.496788: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 65536)             6553600   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 65536)             262144    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu (LeakyReLU)      (None, 65536)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 16, 16, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTran (None, 16, 16, 256)       3211264   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 16, 16, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 16, 16, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 32, 32, 128)       1605632   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 32, 32, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 32, 32, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 64, 64, 64)        401408    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 64, 64, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 64, 64, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTr (None, 128, 128, 3)       4800      
=================================================================
Total params: 12,040,640
Trainable params: 11,908,672
Non-trainable params: 131,968
_________________________________________________________________
2021-01-22 00:12:08.793121: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:09.334054: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:09.335006: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1838] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
2021-01-22 00:12:09.337482: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-22 00:12:10.319075: I tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:308] SubProcess ended with return code: 0

2021-01-22 00:12:10.349989: I tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:308] SubProcess ended with return code: 0

Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 32)        4736      
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 64, 64, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 64, 64, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 64)        51264     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_5 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)       204928    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_6 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 16, 16, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 16, 16, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 32768)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 32769     
=================================================================
Total params: 293,697
Trainable params: 293,697
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Loading Dataset
Finished Loading Dataset
(46957, 128, 128, 3)
Finished Organizing Dataset
No pickle found
2021-01-22 00:12:42.680822: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:80] Allocation of 9232121856 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you should never see 100% memory usage if you include your virtual memory with that large of a margin difference even using a NVMe drive due to caching slowdowns. Beyond that TensorFlow throws that flag predictively. GPU computing on TensorFlow tends to be RAM heavy. My best recommendation is to lower your batch size by a factor of 2 until it runs.

Another point which I’m not sure if it’s correlated is that in nVidia’s Isaac app forums have reported a significant number of issues with RTX3xxx cards.

Comment: A batch size of 1 has the exact same number of exceeding bits as a batch size of 128. I understand that virtual memory is a lot slower, and I'm ok with that. But it just doesn't seem to want to use it. I tried updating TensorFlow to 2.4.1 but it didn't help. @alexander-jh